# How can I disable refresh mode in scrollview?

Tags: android-studio

In Android Studio, when we drag the scroll view to the end, a shadow is displayed at the bottom, how can I disable it?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `android:overScrollMode="never"` attribute inside the `<ScrollView>`